# Highcharts in InfoWindow on Google Maps

Tags: ajax, google-maps, highcharts, infowindow

I would like to understand why the chart doesn't display inside the InfoWindow, after the first click.

As you can see on the fiddle I provide, on the first click on any marker, the chart displays correctly inside the InfoWindow, but on the next click on a marker the InfoWindow stays blank and no chart is displayed. I would like to understand why it stays blank and if there is a possibility of fixing it so at each click on a marker, the chart will display as intended.

```
var marker, i;
var contentDiv = '<div id="container" style="height:350px; width:350px"></div>';

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][2], locations[i][3]),
        map: map,
        title: locations[i][0]+ " (" + locations[i][1] + " stars)"
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
        var selectedname = locations[i][0];
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        stopAnimation(marker);
        $.ajax({
                success: function(data) {
                    iw.open(map, marker);                       
                    iw.setContent(contentDiv);
                    dataChart = {   
                        chart: {
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            renderTo: document.getElementById('container'),
                            zoomType: 'x',
                            type:"spline",
                            height:350,
                            width:350,
                            marginRight:40
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                            x: -20 //center
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                            x: -20
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            title: {
                                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                            },
                            plotLines: [{
                                value: 0,
                                width: 1,
                                color: '#808080'
                            }]
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            valueSuffix: '°C'
                        },
                        legend: {
                            layout: 'vertical',
                            align: 'right',
                            verticalAlign: 'middle',
                            borderWidth: 0
                        },
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Tokyo',
                            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
                        }, {
                            name: 'New York',
                            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
                        }, {
                            name: 'Berlin',
                            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
                        }, {
                            name: 'London',
                            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
                        }]
                    }
                    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(dataChart);
                }

        });
            return false
        }
    })
    (marker, i));
}
```

Here is the fiddle of the entire code : http://jsfiddle.net/YRNHP/5/

Thank you in advance,
Pouyo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a timing issue.

You call `iw.setContent(contentDiv);` and then immediately call Highcharts.  Highcharts is acting on an element in the `contentDiv` variable, but has it become part of the DOM yet?  When you reuse your InfoWindow, its part of the DOM from the last call, but then it gets swapped out; which does Highcharts use?

I'd add a `domready` event to your InfoWindow (that way you know the contentDiv is inserted and available) and use that to init the Highchart

```
google.maps.event.addListener(iw,'domready',function(){
   // draw chart here
});

// later on ...

iw.open(map, marker);                   
iw.setContent(contentDiv);  // when contentDiv is part of DOM above function fires
```

See udpated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YRNHP/3/).